# Is there any way to set default time zone for location basis..?

Tags: php, time

Is there any way to set default timezone for location basis..???

For Example user comes from Karachi,Pakistan and timezone will set automatically.

Answer (score -1):

You have to use JS to solve this problem.

http://www.onlineaspect.com/2007/06/08/auto-detect-a-time-zone-with-javascript/ how to set using JS

http://onlineaspect.com/examples/timezone/index.html  shows ur timezone.

should do the trick